# eclipse cannot update and cannot install new software

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

I cannot install new softwares (plugins) in my eclipse, also I cannot update it.

```
     Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

     Version: Kepler Service Release 2
     Build id: 20140224-0627
```

- Check for updates

  No updates were found
  Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
  No repository found at http://update.eclemma.org/.
  No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler.
  No repository found at http://veloeclipse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/update/.

**I can use the eclipse internal web-browser, and I have also set the proxy settings**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i tried deleting my eclipse and downloading the latest version  (kepler as of now) 
And it worked .

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes kepler update fails on Java 7. Use Java 6 instead.

Comment: how to i change java, jdk ?? or jre ?

Comment: ok tried uninstalling jre 7 and installing jre 6, but no change, same error.